# Passing optional number of arguments to a flag Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I want to be able to pass to my python script 1 or 2 parameters, so I would be able to call it like this:

```
dfuMaker.py --bin {file} {address}
```

Where address can have a default value if not passed.

Currently, this is how I'm defining the argument.

```
cmdParser.add_argument(
    '--bin', action='store', nargs=2, required=True)
```

And of course when trying to pass just 1 argument it fails with the error:

```
DFUMaker: error: argument --bin: expected 2 arguments
```

Comment: Use `nargs='+', `argparse.ONE_OR_MORE`.  It won't complain about more than 2, but you can test for that after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a custom type.

```
def file_address_pair(s):
    x = s.split(",", 1)
    if len(x) == 1:
        x.append(DEFAULT_ADDRESS)
    return x


p.add_argument("--bin", type=file_address_pair)
```

Despite the name, the `type` argument can be any callable that takes a `str` and returns a value; it doesn't have to be an actual Python type.

Then you can use either of

```
dfuMaker.py --bin f
dfuMaker.py --bin f,addr
```

Comment: Great idea. I will make it into a class (cpp programmer here) and add it to my code.

Comment: This kind of value tweak can also be performed after parsing.

Comment: @hpaulj One nice thing about using the type is that any exception that might get raised by the type function will be caught and converted into a usage error for you.

Comment: @chepner Exactly, I'm using asserts to enforce rules on the type.